# google analytics transactionId and pagePath dimensions in the same query

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am trying to retrieve for each transaction on my website the pagepath. I am not really interesting into any metrics. I was trying to use transactionRevenue but I get the error

> 400: 'Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together.'

What is a suitable metric to use when these two dimensions are together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error 400: 'Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried
>   together.'

Not all dimensions and metrics can be queried together which ever ones you have chosen you cant query them together.  Its best to check the [dimensions and metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) to check if you can query them together.

[ga:pagePath](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) can be combined with [ga:transactionRevenue](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce&jump=ga_transactionrevenue) so that should not be your problem.  I am not sure what other dimensions and metrics you have in there.

**Query with out metrics**

The [reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#metrics) requires that you send at least one metric.  It is not possible to make a request with out any metrics.

> •Any request must supply at least one metric; a request cannot consist
>   only of dimensions.

What I don't understand is you speak of not wanting any metrics yet [ga:transactionRevenue](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce&jump=ga_transactionrevenue) is a metric.